# MSVC/VS is not detecting any Windows SDK related things - includes, libraries etc

Tags: python, windows, visual-c++

I installed Visual Studio Build Tools 2022 from the official website, checking the "C++ desktop development" box. It installed successfully. However, when I try to use it to compile some Python library, various errors thrown by the compiler shows that MSVC is not aware of any Windows SDK related files on my system, although they are all there and I used default location to install them. To trouble shoot, I uninstalled Windows SDK from VS installer and installed it separately using https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-sdk/. Same issue still persists. Most online solutions suggest for a reinstall of the Windows SDK, but I have done it over 5 times, switching around different versions (Windows 10, Windows 11 two each), and nothing changed. I have also checked and confirmed the following registry values indeed points to my installation folder:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows Kits\Installed Roots\
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows Kits\Installed Roots\
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows Kits\Installed Roots
```

Some of the errors I met were header files cannot be found errors where the header files exist in the Windows SDK directory, e.g. `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22621.0\ucrt` and `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22621.0\shared`. Manually adding these folders in using setup.py works as a workaround, but definitely not a solution.

However, there is another issue where it cannot find certain `.lib` files too, and those files also belong in Windows SDK installation, for example, `kernel32.lib` which exists on my system in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Lib\10.0.22621.0\um\x64`. Sure, I can also edit this in setup.py, but if I have to do this for every single setup.py I get, it would be very tiring.

When I try to run `set include` in VS x64 native developer command prompt, it only shows my VS code related paths: `INCLUDE=E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.34.31933\include;E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include`. However from online sources, it should also include windows SDK related paths.

I do not have a "cpp properties" file to set like many online solutions suggest because I am not using VS/VS code. I am just doing a `python setup.py build`.

Windows SDK can be seen with the correct version in control panel.

The Python library I am trying to build is https://github.com/facebookresearch/xformers, and it seems like I am the only one having this issue building, and it should not be any issue from the python library side.